# Calling OpenWeather API from Watson Assistant: "Direct CloudFunctions call was not successful"

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant, ibm-cloud-functions

I am trying to use the openweathermap API with Watson Assistant, but I am getting "Webhook call was not successful. Response code is [404]. (and there is 1 more error in the log)."

(I am working from the book by Sabharwal, et al., with my own improvisations for the obsolete elements, like @sys-location.)

I created a Cloud Functions Action called "https://us-south.functions.appdomain.cloud/api/v1/web/my-account-email%40dev/default/Weather-Connection" and checked Enable as Web Action. The action code was imported from the git repo for the book:

```
let rp = require('request-promise')
function main(params) {
    const options = {
        uri: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + encodeURIComponent(params.object_of_interest)+ "&units=metric&APPID=19e8588cb3d7d0623e3a5a8ec529232f" ,
        json: true
    }
    return rp(options)
    .then(res => {
        WeatherReport = "Current Temperature : " +res.main.temp+ ", Pressure : " + res.main.pressure + ", Humidity : " + res.main.humidity + ", temp min : " + res.main.temp_min + " , temp max : " + res.main.temp_max
        return { WeatherReport
        } 
    })
}
```

In the Assistant Options the webhook URI is set to
`https://us-south.functions.appdomain.cloud/api/v1/web/my-account-email%40dev/default/Weather-Connection.json`.

The "Assistant responds" JSON is
The "Assistant responds" JSON is

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "/my-account-email%40dev/default/Weather-Connection.json",
      "type": "cloud_function",
      "parameters": {
        "object_of_interest": "$location"
      },
      "credentials": "$credentials",
      "result_variable": "$response"
    }
  ],
  "context": {
    "credentials": {
      "api_key": "[my-openweathermap-api-key]"
    },
    "object_of_interest": "@object_of_interest"
  }
}
```

For debugging, I included a dialog node that displays the value of $location, and it is okay (e.g. "London").

The "Try it out" pane prints {"cloud_functions_call_error":"The requested resource does not exist."} When I click on the Error icon I get a Runtime error pop-up saying, `Direct CloudFunctions call was not successful. Http response code is [404]. (and there is 1 more error in the log)`.

I am not getting any output from running the CLI command `ibmcloud fn activation list`(I'm not sure that's the right way to check the logs).

I have tested the Weather-Connection function by invoking the Action with parameter `{"object_of_interest": "London"}`, and it works.

Everything is deployed in the same region (us-south) and namespace.

I can't think of anything else to try.

Comment: Correction: now I _am_ getting logs. The Status is coming back as `application error`

Comment: "response": {
        "status": "application error",
        "statusCode": 0,
        "success": false,
        "result": {
            "error": {
                "error": {
                    "cod": "400",
                    "message": "bad query"
                },

Comment: You can check activitations and also invoke using the browser UI for Cloud Functions: https://cloud.ibm.com/functions/dashboard

Comment: Check what was passed from Watson Assistant to the Function, whether the received payload has the expected format.

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik. The logs show there is an argument "q=undefined", which says to me that the value of the location variable isn't making it into the request. I'll keep digging.

Comment: This IBM Cloud solution tutorial passes variables to Cloud Functions. The workspace is provided on GitHub. In case you want to see a working sample. https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/solution-tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-slack-chatbot-database-watson

Comment: Thanks. I figured out why the location wasn't getting passed to the cloud function, and now the activation log shows that I am getting a correct response. However, Watson Assistant still throws a 404 code and there seems to be nothing in the webhook result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just cracked it. I was trying to show the result using the text `response is <? $webhook_result_1.response ?>` when it should just have been `response is <? $webhook_result_1 ?>`.